# Execute a C program using Docker windows

Tags: windows, docker, cross-compiling

When ever I try to run the docker image, I am getting the following error.

```
/bin/sh: 1: [.\helloworld]: not found.
```

Can anyone help me out to resolve please...

```
RUN apt-get update -y && apt-get install -y gcc
RUN mkdir \helloworld
COPY . \helloworld
WORKDIR \
RUN g++ -o helloworld Test.c
CMD [".\helloworld"]
```

Comment: In Linux, the directory separator is `/`, not \.

Comment: Getting this error `docker : The command '/bin/sh -c g++ -o helloworld Test.c' returned a non-zero code: 127` after changing it to `/`. @Kryten

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to pack and ship a simple c application in docker without the gcc compiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58129302/how-to-pack-and-ship-a-simple-c-application-in-docker-without-the-gcc-compiler)

Comment: Also don't compile C code with c++ compiler. ```RUN gcc -o helloworld Test.c``` after changing all occurrence of ```\``` to ```/```